# How to transfer a C# object to C++ when standard serialization cannot be used

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2013, managed-c++

I have an object in C# I cannot modify. I would like to be able to use it later on in C++ using managed C++ to interface with it.

The problem is that I have to somehow store the object in order to recreate it when I will need it.

This sounds a lot like serialization but sadly I cannot seem to be able to use that technique as I get the following message when serializing the object using `XmlSerializer` :

> ClassName cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor.

As I cannot modify the C# object, what other technique could I use to transfer this object ?

Is there another way to serialize the object that would bypass this limitation ?

Comment: You could write all properties of the C# object into a file in whatever format you are happy with; you don't need to use the XML serializer.

Comment: Are you trying to serialize it in C# ? And why not wrapping your object data into a class that you can modify ?

Comment: Yes I am trying to serialize it in C#. Would it work to encapsulate the object into another one I actually can modify ?

Comment: Create a wrapper that exposes the object via COM?